# Yocto - tools-profile' in IMAGE_FEATURES (added via EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES) is not a valid image feature

Tags: yocto

I am trying to install the tools-profile in the yocto but I get an error saying that tools-profile is not a valid option. How can I debug this? How to check why is it failing? Here is how I tried it.

Here is my bblayers.conf

```
LCONF_VERSION = "7"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-poky \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-gplv2 \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/openembedded-core/meta \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-custom \
  "

BBLAYERS_NON_REMOVABLE ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-poky \
  "
```

In the local.conf, I have added the following.

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks tools-profile"
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late but I will answer this question as this happened to me yesterday.

The issue is that you have an image that inherits only `image.bbclass`. If you look into `image.bbclass` you will see that it doesn't know anything about `tools-profile` but `core-image.bbclass` does.

All you have to do is to change `inherit image` to `inherit core-image` in an image that is throwing the error.

In my case it was `swupdate-image`.